# Corosync & Pacemaker IPTables Rules

Tags: iptables

When using Corosync with two rings via multi-cast addresses 226.94.1.1 (Port 
5405) & 226.94.1.2 (Port 5406) what iptables rules are required to allow two 
nodes to communicate optimally without giving any undue access and making the 
rules too lenient?

I current have:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 5404,5405,5406 -j ACCEPT
```

Will that allow all the communication a Corosync/Pacemaker setup requires for 
both rings?

I have heard arguments that something like:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
```

is required. However I cannot seem to replicate a situation where this assists 
if the first rule I listed above is already in place.

The Red Hat documentation would seem to support the first approach. There is 
some IBM documentation espousing the second but is it just a case of a rule 
that is far too lenient when the first would do the job equally well whilst 
leaving no unnecessary ports open?

I'm leaning more towards the first rule being sufficient but wanted to get some more opinions on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation from Red Hat and IBM specifies rules that actually allow more packets than are really needed.

Multicast IP packets are really not much different from unicast IP packets, the only difference (in addition to the way how they are sent on Layer 2 and routed) is the destination address, which must be in the range 224.0.0.0/4.

As [described on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/655475/261808), the following rules can be used for a single Corosync ring (assuming that the `OUTPUT` chain does not block any traffic):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p igmp -i $corosync_interface -j ACCEPT
for src_addr in $ip_addr_self $ip_addr_partner1 $ip_addr_partner2; do
  iptables -A INPUT -i $corosync_interface -s $src_addr -d $ip_addr_self \
    -p udp --source-port $(($corosync_port - 1)) \
    --destination-port $corosync_port -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A INPUT -i $corosync_interface -s $src_addr -d $ip_addr_mcast \
    -p udp --source-port $(($corosync_port - 1)) \
    --destination-port $corosync_port -j ACCEPT
done
```

In this example, the following variables are assumed to be defined:

- `$corosync_interface`: the network interface which is used by Corosync
- `$ip_addr_self`: the IP address to which Corosync binds locally (specified as `bindnetaddr` in `corosync.conf`)
- `$ip_addr_partner1`, `$ip_addr_partner2`: the IP addresses of the other Corosync nodes - more can be added if the cluster has more than three nodes.
- `$ip_addr_mcast`: the multicast address used for Corosync (specified as `mcastaddr` in `corosync.conf`)
- `$corosync_port`: the (destination) port used by Corosync (specified as `mcastport` in `corosync.conf`)

For multiple rings, the same approach can be used with the interface name, IP addresses and port numbers changed to match the respective definitions.

In comparison to the rules specified in the documentation, the rules above are restricted to specific interfaces, source addresses and source ports and the destination port is limited to a single port. Actually, Corosync does not send packets to more than one destination port, it just uses a different port (destination port minus one) for sending data than for receiving data.